# The number of tilings of a grid

Tags: code-golf, grid, set-partitions, tiling

**Setup:**
A *block* is any rectangular array of squares, specified by its dimensions \$(w,h)\$. A *grid* is any finite ordered list of blocks. For example, \$\lambda = ((3,2),(3,1),(1,2))\$ defines a grid.

Let \$\lambda\$ and \$\mu\$ be two grids with equal area.

A *tiling of \$\lambda\$ by \$\mu\$* is any rearrangement of the squares of \$\mu\$ into the shape of \$\lambda\$ satisfying two properties:

1. horizontally adjacent squares of \$\mu\$ remain horizontally adjacent in \$\lambda\$, and
2. vertically adjacent squares of \$\lambda\$ come from vertically adjacent squares of \$\mu\$.

In other words, while rearranging one is allowed to make horizontal cuts to the blocks of \$\mu\$ but not vertical cuts, and one is allowed to place blocks into \$\lambda\$ side-by-side, but not on top of one another.

Two tilings of \$\lambda\$ by \$\mu\$ are considered *equivalent* if they can be rearranged into one another by any combination of either permuting squares within a column or reordering the columns of a block.

**Problem:** Write a function \$T(\mu,\lambda)\$ which computes the number of inequivalent tilings of a grid \$\lambda\$ by another grid \$\mu\$ of equal area.

**Specifications:** You may use any data type you would like to specify a grid.

**Examples:**

1. The grid \$\lambda=((1,2),(1,2),(1,1),(2,1))\$ admits a tiling by \$\mu=((1,3),(1,2),(2,1))\$ given by

[image]

There is exactly one other inequivalent tiling given by

[image]

(Since the two differently colored columns of height \$2\$ are not part of the same block, they cannot be permuted.)

2. The three displayed tilings of \$\lambda=((3,1))\$ by \$\mu=((1,2),(1,1))\$ are equivalent:

[image]

3. Let \$\lambda\$ be an arbitrary grid of area \$n\$ and let \$\lambda[(w,h)]\$ denote the number of blocks of \$\lambda\$ of dimension \$w \times h\$. Then \$T(\lambda,\lambda) = \prod_{w,h\geq 1} \lambda[(w,h)]!\$ and \$T(\lambda,((n,1))) = 1\$.
4. The matrix of values of \$T(\mu,\lambda)\$ for all pairs of grids of area \$3\$ (row is \$\mu\$, column is \$\lambda\$):

|  | ((1,3)) | ((1,2),(1,1)) | ((1,1),(1,1),(1,1)) | ((2,1),(1,1)) | ((3,1)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ((1,3)) | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ((1,2),(1,1)) | 0 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| ((1,1),(1,1),(1,1)) | 0 | 0 | 6 | 3 | 1 |
| ((2,1),(1,1)) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| ((3,1)) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This looks like a great challenge, although if you haven't already I'd recommend checking out the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future ones.

Comment: This is a well written and interesting challenge. However, it would be much appreciated to include some test cases where only \$\lambda\$, \$\mu\$ and the expected output are provided, so that the answers can be more easily tested.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've just added all possible values for grids of area 3.

Comment: You may want to provide a test case with at least one block of size \$w>1\$, \$h>1\$.

Comment: I've just generalized example 3 to include such test cases.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>255</s>…<s>247</s></sup> 242 bytes

- -2 bytes thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor), for suggesting a better partitioning function `q`.
- -8 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs), for suggesting `[a!!i|i:_<-u]` and removing an unnecessary `map`.

```hs
(a#b)c d=sum[1|g<-nub$(permutations(zipWith replicate b[0..]>>=id)>>=q)>>=mapM(q.sort),l g==l c,and[l x==h&&all(==x!!0)x&&sum[a!!i|i:_<-u]==w|(u,w,h)<-zip3 g c d,x<-u]]
q=foldr(\h t->map([h]:)t++[(h:y):z|y:z<-t])[[]]
l=length
import Data.List
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLNbqMwEL7nKRwWpbawUdPcWIy00l5WSk897MFBlRNcsNYYggcljfLuWUOD0vbQHjzWeL6fmZEr6f4pYy66bpsO0G8JMl5rBxcsf2zJDhXc9bVYnsuU2X4b4lZ1dQ8SdGMdPun2r4YKdao1eidBoa24j@M8y7guiI/7IdSyfcT72Hl9Qg0qOTdoR6UthEFHzqvFQhqDOT/O5/fkuFgMhnI@12edPKeszzk/nHFPD7QiKfOWK1Qi3xg9DsV8tucvjSk6vKkQsMybYVHlCYEoErhKXklyOr8mp5RBToTweMONsiVUM8Y@jVxLbXnRzBAC5cClbBDrlCyS5Ak6bUuWCfzHAvWH5CQ@NF3h0jArFay1VZ5nFCAra@V423fKl8Tdrzu/EF8at7DBQC1hWduDV1zb0EZRgDgKoshVzQEBCf2Ab/ZvQp45gYPgJvP8TiYMNuAF7LfcF@Pro8AnIAnR1Nk4/sQb2/Pi49PXbEfrG3tcBJZ0S3hvR/RPvKPFlLkr6GoyTI6n70beOd6avwi8pCuSo@F@INTH5TVbXrPb28OHbDXc/wE)

A grid \$\mu\$ is represented as a pair \$(W_\mu,H_\mu)\$ where \$W_\mu\$, \$H_\mu\$ are lists containing, respectively, the widths and the heights of the blocks in \$\mu\$.

The relevant function is `(#)`, which takes as input four lists: `a`\$=W_\mu\$, `b`\$=H_\mu\$, `c`\$=W_\lambda\$, `d`\$=H_\lambda\$. It returns the integer \$T(\mu,\lambda)\$.

Comment: I noticed you have a function `q` that generates all partitions. You can use a slightly shorter version I had written from some previous challenge: `q=foldr(\h t->map([h]:)t++[(h:y):z|y:z<-t])[[]]`.

Comment: @xnor Nice, thanks! I should probably explain the code, so that you can suggest other amazing golfs ^^

Comment: `sum[a!!head i|i<-u]` can be shortened to `sum[a!!i|i:_<-u]`.

Comment: `nub$(permutations(zipWith replicate b[0..]>>=id)>>=q)>>=mapM(q.sort)` saves 5 more bytes. (`concatMap f $ map g x == concatMap (f.g) x`)

Comment: @Delfad0r Wow, impressive! I'd be very interested in reading an explanation of the code.